# GraphQL: Error: Schema query must be Object Type but got: [object Object]

Tags: graphql

I'm currently trying to inherit schemas for a rootQuery in order to get more modularity. The setup currently looks as follows:

invoiceSchema.js

```
import {
    GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLInt,
} from 'graphql';
export default new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Invoice',
    description: 'A monthly billing invoice for an organization',
    fields: () => ({
        amountDue: {
            type: GraphQLInt,
            description: 'The amount the card will be charged (total + startingBalance with a min value of 0)'
        },
    })
});
```

rootQuery.js

```
import {
    GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLString,
    GraphQLInt,
    GraphQLList,
    GraphQLID
} from 'graphql';
import Invoice from './invoiceSchema';

export default {
    Invoice: {
        type: Invoice,
        resolve(parentValue, args){
            return 'Hello world';
        } 
    }
};
```

schema.js

```
import query from './rootQuery';
import {GraphQLSchema} from 'graphql';

export default new GraphQLSchema({query});
```

---

When trying to do the following error and hoped for some help and insight, as what I'm exporting in invoiceSchema.js is clearly an ObjectType and not an object Object.

```
C:\project\node_modules\graphql\jsutils\invariant.js:19
    throw new Error(message);
    ^

Error: Schema query must be Object Type but got: [object Object].
    at invariant (C:\project\node_modules\graphql\jsutils\invariant.js:19:11)
    at new GraphQLSchema (C:\project\node_modules\graphql\type\schema.js:72:88)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:/project/api/schema/schema.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
    at loader (C:\project\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\project\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:517:17)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Actually got the idea from [here](https://github.com/ParabolInc/action/tree/master/src/server/graphql) and I'm wondering why it doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your root query needs to be an instance of `GraphQLObjectType`, however, `rootQuery.js` is exporting a plain Object instead. You'll need to change your export to something like this:

```
export default new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootQuery',
  fields: () => ({
    invoice: {
        type: Invoice,
        resolve(parentValue, args){
            return 'Hello world';
        } 
    }
  })
};
```

Note: it's common practice to keep all field names, including query and mutation names, in camelCase and use PascalCase for type names, to help distinguish between the two.

Also, if you are modularizing your schema, you may find it helpful to utilize [`graphql-tools`](http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-tools/generate-schema.html) for generating your schema instead. IMO, it makes your schema more readable and helps avoid some of the more common pitfalls you may face when modularizing a schema. The docs have a great example of how to modularize your schema with `makeExecutableSchema` [here](http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-tools/generate-schema.html#modularizing).

Comment: Thanks! Using it as follows now: `export default new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootQuery',
  fields: () => ({
     ...Invoice
  })
};` which then results in error `Error: RootQuery.name field config must be an object` - which is weird since it's referencing the string of the query's name. Maybe you also know how to fix that.

Comment: The spread operator there isn't appropriate. You're basically setting the fields to your Invoice type, which won't work. `fields` need to be either an object, or a function that returns that object. In either case, that object maps each field name to another object that contains details for that field (like `type`, `args`, `resolve`, etc.)

Comment: `{ ...Invoice }`